# Sort List of List in Python based on days of the week

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of daily temperature, shown below:

```
weekly_temperature = [['Saturday', 100], ['Wednesday', 95], ['Friday', 80],
['Monday', 95], ['Sunday', 90], ['Tuesday', 100], ['Thursday', 85]]
```

How do I sort this list based on days of the week, starting from Monday to Sunday?

I would like the sorted output to look like below:

```
weekly_temperature = [['Monday', 95], ['Tuesday', 100], ['Wednesday', 95], 
['Thursday', 85], ['Friday', 80], ['Saturday', 100], ['Sunday', 90]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `time.strptime` to parse the day of the week, so you can use it as a key for sorting:

```
import time

weekly_temperature = [['Saturday', 100], ['Wednesday', 95], ['Friday', 80],
['Monday', 95], ['Sunday', 90], ['Tuesday', 100], ['Thursday', 85]]
print(sorted(weekly_temperature, key=lambda t: time.strptime(t[0], '%A')))
```

This outputs:

```
[['Monday', 95], ['Tuesday', 100], ['Wednesday', 95], ['Thursday', 85], ['Friday', 80], ['Saturday', 100], ['Sunday', 90]]
```

Note that `time.strptime` depends on your locale settings, and if you want to be on the safe side you can save your current time locale, set it to the standard `C` locale, parse your day of the week, and then restore your local setting:

```
import time
import locale

orig_locale = locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME)
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'C')
weekly_temperature = [['Saturday', 100], ['Wednesday', 95], ['Friday', 80],
['Monday', 95], ['Sunday', 90], ['Tuesday', 100], ['Thursday', 85]]
print(sorted(weekly_temperature, key=lambda t: time.strptime(t[0], '%A')))
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, orig_locale)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
weekly_temperature = [['Saturday', 100], ['Wednesday', 95], ['Friday', 80], ['Monday', 95], ['Sunday', 90], ['Tuesday', 100], ['Thursday', 85]]
d = {
    "Monday": 1,
    "Tuesday": 2,
    "Wednesday": 3,
    "Thursday": 4,
    "Friday": 5,
    "Saturday": 6,
    "Sunday": 7
}

week = sorted(weekly_temperature, key=lambda x: d[x[0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an indirection to a structure that will convert day names into a sort key in the appropriate order:

For example:

```
days = "Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday"


weekly_temperature = [['Saturday', 100], ['Wednesday', 95], ['Friday', 80], 
                      ['Monday', 95], ['Sunday', 90], ['Tuesday', 100],
                      ['Thursday', 85]]

weekly_temperature.sort(key=lambda t:days.index(t[0]))

[['Monday', 95], ['Tuesday', 100], ['Wednesday', 95], ['Thursday', 85],
 ['Friday', 80], ['Saturday', 100], ['Sunday', 90]]
```

You can use a dictionary or a list instead of a string as long as you manage to turn the day name into the appropriate sort key.